# Python: compare first element of lists effectively

Tags: python, list, compare, append

In Python I have a list called "list1" containing lists of variable length.

I want to append a second list "add" to that long list iff the first element of add is not the first element of any of the lists in list1.

This code works:

```
list1 = [["a", 5, 9, 22], ["b", 10, 1], ["c"], ["d", 42]]

add = ["e", 1, 31]
add2 = ["b", 1, 31]

temp = []
for e in list1:
    temp.append(e[0])

if add[0] not in temp:
    list1.append(add)
```

As expected, add ist added to list1 while add2 would not be added.

However, I wonder if there is a more elegant and effective way that avoids creating a temporary list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test with `all()` and a generator expression:

```
if any(add[0] != elem[0] for elem in list1):
    list1.append(add)
```

The `all()` function loops over the included generator expression testing that it'll onl contain `True` values, but will stop if it comes across a `False` (where `add[0]` is equal to `elem[0]`). This saves having to loop through *all* of `list1` to find out if `elem[0]` is already present.

Comment: I guess they actually want `if all(add[0] != elem[0])...`

Comment: @thg435: Uhm, yes, indeed. Inverted my logic there, corrected.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this will break if any of the lists involved are empty. If that's possible with your data, you can add a filter to the generator expression: `if all(add[0] != elem[0] for elem in list1 if elem)...`